# Why is 英语和汉语我都会说 correct and 我会说都英语和汉语 incorrect?

Tags: grammar, sentence-structure, word-order

While studying today's lesson I came across this sentence:

> 英语和汉语我都会说。

The lesson also says that I cannot say:

> 我会说都英语和汉语。

I imagine it's because of 都, so if I omit it, would it be correct to say 我会说英语和汉语?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Yes, without 都, you can say "我会说英语和汉语" The reason is unlike the English word "both" which is placed before the objects,  "都" must be placed after the objects

1. I can speak [English and Chinese]
2. I can speak [**both**] [English and Chinese]
3. 我会说[英语和汉语]
4. [英语和汉语]我[**都**]会说
5. 我[英语和汉语][**都**]会说

Notice in #4 and #5 the object [英语和汉语] is placed before 都

"我会[**都**]说 [英语和汉语]" and "我会说[**都**][英语和汉语]" violated this rule.

Note:

"都" in "我都会说英语和汉语" (I too, can speak English and Chinese) means "also" or "too". It is different usage of "都"